# Amazon instant Video

Tags: amazon

I'm currently experiencing an error in the Amazon instant Video that reads that the player was unable to update.   I download the flash player required but still the problem in Firefox and Ubuntu Web browser in Ubuntu 14.04 lts.  Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type the following commands on a terminal to get it working -

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mjblenner/ppa-hal

sudo apt-get update     

sudo apt-get install hal

sudo mkdir /etc/hal/fdi/preprobe

sudo mkdir /etc/hal/fdi/information

/usr/sbin/hald --daemon=yes --verbose=yes

rm -rf ~/.adobe
```